# Multi Dimensional NSArray to NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsarray

Firstly refer to the graphic show below:

[image]

I have an NSArray that contains 9 Elements.
Each of these 9 elements contain a further 5 Elements.

What I would like to do is take the `[*][1]` from each an place them into another which will only contain these dates.

How is this best achieved ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray * results = [@[] mutableCopy];

for (NSArray *details in self.fuelDetailsForSelectedBike){
    [result addObject:details[1]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems rather basic, loop through the main array and for each object (that is an array) take it's second element and add it to the result.